# Understanding Sentence -- blasting things off

Tags: idioms, sentence

I am having trouble in understanding the last sentence. Could you please simplify the sentence? Thanks!

> IF HUMAN BEINGS should ever wish to build bases on the Moon, those bases will need
> water. Residents will require it not only for their own sustenance but also as a raw
> material for rocket fuel to power adventures farther afield—Mars, for example. **Given
> the cost of blasting things off the surface of Earth, however, such a base would be best
> served by finding its water locally.**

Source: https://www.economist.com/science-and-technology/2020/10/26/there-is-now-cast-iron-evidence-for-water-on-the-moon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blastoff?s=t) definition of "blastoff"

> the launching of a rocket, guided missile, or spacecraft.

Blasting off is the process if launching something, in your example it's referring to spacecraft that would carry water to the Moon.